# ORA-00906 error with my INSERT SQl STATEMENT; This works in DB2 database

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am having an error with my sql query in an oracle database. It says "ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis"

Here is my SQL statement:

```sql
insert into UBTB_ACCOUNTTRANSLIMIT(
  UBACCTTRANSLIMITID,
  UBACCOUNTID,
  UBTRANSACTIONGROUPID,
  UBISACTIVE,
  UBEXPOSUREAMOUNT,
  UBEXPOSURECOUNT,
  UBEXPOSUREREVIEWFREQ,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITCOUNT,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITAMT,
  UBLIMITEXCESSACTION,
  UBLASTREVIEWDATE,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITYPE,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITID,
  UBREVIEWMONTH,
  UBREVIEWDAY,
  VERSIONNUM
) 
SELECT UBACCTTRANSLIMITID,
       ACCOUNTID,
       UBTRANSACTIONGROUPID,
       UBISACTIVE,
       UBEXPOSUREAMOUNT,
       UBEXPOSURECOUNT,
       UBEXPOSUREREVIEWFREQ,
       UBTRANSACTIONLIMITCOUNT,
       UBTRANSACTIONLIMITAMT,
       UBLIMITEXCESSACTION,
       UBLASTREVIEWDATE,
       UBTRANSACTIONLIMITYPE,
       UBTRANSACTIONLIMITID,
       UBREVIEWMONTH,
       UBREVIEWDAY,
       VERSIONNUM
FROM   (
  SELECT UB_CONCAT(
           '20230503184525443',
           cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ACCOUNTID) as varchar)
         ) as UBACCTTRANSLIMITID,
         ACCOUNTID,
         'Y' AS UBEXPOSUREREVIEWFREQ,
         0 AS UBLIMITEXCESSACTION,
         '0' AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITYPE,
         'TRANSGROUP1' AS UBTRANSACTIONGROUPID,
         1000.000000 AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITAMT,
         0 AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITCOUNT,
         'LIMITJPY1' AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITID,
         'Y' AS UBISACTIVE,
         {d '2023-05-03'} AS UBLASTREVIEWDATE,
         0 AS UBEXPOSUREAMOUNT,
         0 AS UBEXPOSURECOUNT,
         '01' AS UBREVIEWMONTH,
         '3' AS UBREVIEWDAY,
         0 AS VERSIONNUM
  FROM   ACCOUNT
  WHERE PRODUCTCONTEXTCODE = ?
) VALUELIST
```

I was expecting what might be the cause of the error my sql statement seems fine

Comment: 1. Remove all the columns and expressions. 2. Add one expression in a time and execute the statement. 3. Repeat steps 1-2 until you get an error. 4. Post a question about **this specific** change. Manual debugging of the text is very inefficient compared to the actual database model and the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
{d '2023-05-03'} AS UBLASTREVIEWDATE
```

In Oracle, use date literal:

```
DATE '2023-05-03' AS UBLASTREVIEWDATE
```

---

Other values don't look suspicious, so - try with that and say if it still doesn't work, but then provide some more info (and test case).

Comment: how about in the varchar section, I have seen several issue putting up a length with it. Does it have no issue with an insert statement?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you illustrate it (post an example)?

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot - learn something new every day! (have deleted my previous comment so as not to mislead others)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||` operator instead of `UB_CONCAT` (unless `UB_CONCAT` is a user-defined function) and `CAST` and a date literal instead of `{d '2023-05-03'}`. You also do not need to use a sub-query (and could remove `AS column_alias` in the `SELECT` query as they are unnecessary but they could be kept to help document your code):

```sql
insert into UBTB_ACCOUNTTRANSLIMIT(
  UBACCTTRANSLIMITID,
  UBACCOUNTID,
  UBTRANSACTIONGROUPID,
  UBISACTIVE,
  UBEXPOSUREAMOUNT,
  UBEXPOSURECOUNT,
  UBEXPOSUREREVIEWFREQ,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITCOUNT,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITAMT,
  UBLIMITEXCESSACTION,
  UBLASTREVIEWDATE,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITYPE,
  UBTRANSACTIONLIMITID,
  UBREVIEWMONTH,
  UBREVIEWDAY,
  VERSIONNUM
) 
SELECT '20230503184525443' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ACCOUNTID) as UBACCTTRANSLIMITID,
       ACCOUNTID,
       'Y' AS UBEXPOSUREREVIEWFREQ,
       0 AS UBLIMITEXCESSACTION,
       '0' AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITYPE,
       'TRANSGROUP1' AS UBTRANSACTIONGROUPID,
       1000.000000 AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITAMT,
       0 AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITCOUNT,
       'LIMITJPY1' AS UBTRANSACTIONLIMITID,
       'Y' AS UBISACTIVE,
       DATE '2023-05-03' AS UBLASTREVIEWDATE,
       0 AS UBEXPOSUREAMOUNT,
       0 AS UBEXPOSURECOUNT,
       '01' AS UBREVIEWMONTH,
       '3' AS UBREVIEWDAY,
       0 AS VERSIONNUM
FROM   ACCOUNT
WHERE PRODUCTCONTEXTCODE = ?
```